# Do these hadiths permit violence

Tags: hadith-interpretation, war

Sahih Muslim 31:5917 and 31:5918  say that the Muslims should fight but here it is not for self defence.

"Fight with them until they bear testimony to the fact that there is no god but Allah and Muhammad is his Messenger, and when they do that then their blood and their riches are inviolable from your hands but what is justified by law and their reckoning is with Allah."

Normally wars are fought in self defence not like this. Is there a specific reason were they kaafir who may have stolen something? If the prophet wanted to guide them did it have to be done through war and violence?

Answer (score 1):

The "them" here is the Quraysh tribe of Makkah. They had just broken the Treaty of Hudaibiyah, and the Prophet (SAW) declared war on them. The Muslims were not allowed to accept another peace with them since they had broken the peace already.

Comment: Please provide with source and reference I have the same question